# Is existing a Web browser 'chrond' (or equivalent) mechanism to use with JavaScript / AJax?

Tags: javascript, events, timer, browser

2015-01-30 @ 16h00_SGT -- Draft

Hi,

While "playing" with 'JavaScript' and 'AJax' for my new Web site, I had the following idea:

"
It would be cool to have something equivalent to 'chrond' into our Web browsers to set up some regular/frequent events like an every second data checking/refreshing job.

So, with a set of methods like:

- ClockDisplayRefresh = new ChronJob(fnClock(), ClockSchedule, (persistence=true;) );
- ...
  "

Now, the questions are:

- "Is there already something like a 'chrond' object with associated methods in the actual (2015-01-30) Web browser's technology ?"
- "Where should I start looking, to satisfy my curiosity and programmer's needs ?"
- "Where should I start looking, to, eventually, develop an addon for my favorite Web browsers ?"

Thank you.

HPS

Answer (score 0):

SetTimeOut and SetInterval are the function for planning an action in the future (or just after the current process in the Thread for certain case)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
setTimeOut(yourFunction, timeInMillis)
```

timeInMillis is a delay, if you want to plan for a certain time, you have to compute it with time=yourDate-new Date()

setTimeOut will call the function once, setInterval will repeat the execution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm going to give a try to 'setInterval()'
Actually, what I have in mind would me more related to a framework to make things simpler to manage by centralising all kind of timed events into one place.
But, since I'm beginning with JavaScript (always managed to avoid it until I decided to give a try to AJax...), I may say something stupid.
I am sorry if I did it.

Comment: No Problem, Thank you for giving your feedback.